# Calendar like horizontal scrolling menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Does anyone know a library I could use to make a slider menu like in the image below?

[slider menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KadTG.jpg)

Like the image, I need to display the days of the week

What I've tried:

(1) Using CAPSPageMenu repo on github but I came to realize this is inefficient for what I need. I only need one view controller, and will have hundreds of menu items (each menu item is a day of the week)

Other possibilities:

(1) Should I create a tableView, rotate it 90 degrees, and allow that to function as the horizontal scrollable menu?

(2) I found a tutorial online that lets me embed a collection view inside a tableView cell... But it seems rather cumbersome to make a cell for every day of the week.

Comment: “rather cumbersome”… well, yeah, if you're crafting each cell by hand using old-world artisanal techniques handed down from father to son for nigh unto 10 generations. Fortunately we have computers these days that can spit out cells by the thousands, lickety-split. Just use a collection view.

Comment: "crafting each cell by hand using old-world artisanal techniques handed down from father to son..." Ouch. No sarcasm there.

Answer (score 2):

That would be pretty easy to create using a UICollectionView. Do NOT try to rotate a table view. That path leads to madness.

You could use the `shortWeekdaySymbols` from `NSCalendar` to get the names of the days of the week.

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIScrollView and put calendar date views inside it.